# Upload to db and then validate or Validate each line and then upload to db

Tags: c#, sql, file-upload

I have a requirement where I have to upload a file to db. 
File will have approx 100K records daily and one per month 8 to 10 million records.

Also there are some field level validations to be performed.

validations are like: are all fields present, do number field contains valid number, date contains valid date, is number in specified range, do the string format match, etc.

There are 3 ways.

```
1: Upload to temp and then validate
- Create a temp table (all string columns), have extra error column
- upload all entries to temp table
- run validation, populate error column if needed
- move valid entries to correct table
```

Cons: entries has to be written twice in db, even correct ones.

```
2: Upload to db directly
- upload all entries directly to table
- check which entries are not uploaded
```

Cons: would need to read each line even after upload, so as good as double read

```
3: Validate and then Upload
- read each line, run all validations on all columns
- if valid then write to db
```

Cons: file reading must be slow than bulk upload to db.

I am writing app in: C# & ASP.NET, DB is Oracle.

Which one of 3 ways is best?

Comment: Validate how, what?  That something that's supposed to be numeric doesn't contain non-digits?  That a field is within a certain range (not specified by a check constraint)?  Option 1 is probably going to require a stored procedure or 'external' code.  Option 2 _may_ be runnable just as an SQL statement - there's also some really basic validation you can do on insert (however, it usually _terminates immediately_ if there's an error - not all valid rows would be written).  3 will be particularily slow, and probably needs to be run 'externally'.

Comment: Validations are like: For num field: check if its number, or its in range or its posetive etc. For text field: check the field format, or its all chars, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aF says, option 2, with the following addition:
Add a table that you can dump 'invalid' rows into.  Then, run a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO InvalidData
SELECT *
FROM InputData
WHERE restrictedColumn NOT IN ('A', 'B')
OR NOT IS_NUMERIC(numberColumn)  -- I'm assuming some version of SQL Server...
```

then dump 'validated' rows into your actual table, excluding 'invalid' rows:

```
INSERT INTO Destination
SELECT a.*
FROM InputData as a
EXCEPTION JOIN InvalidData as b
ON b.id = a.id
```

The `INSERT` will fail if any (other) 'invalid' data is encountered, but should be discoverable.  The 'invalid' table can then be worked to be cleaned up and re-inserted.

Comment: If i understand correctly, i should upload the file to table InputData, then run validations, move invalid rows to InvalidData table & valid rows to Destination. But this would involve like writing each record twice, first to InputData and then to InvalidData/Destination. is there a way to avoid double writing data in db? or this is the best we can achieve?

Comment: Most RDBMSs I'm aware of have some sort of `import` utility, that allows for mass uploads.  The problem is that they're usually not able to perform any validation - they do little more than dump the information to those tables - however, they're _extremely_ fast, compared to single (or even normal blocked) inserts.  They do fail if they encounter 'invalid for column' data (eg, non-digit characters for a numeric column), but (so near as I know) not much/anything more.  So, import to the (all columns char) 'temp' table, then pull rows out.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with option 2.

100k rows are *peanuts* to bulk and query validation.

Comment: There is one particular upload during the month when upload will have approx 8 to 10 million rows.

Comment: The validation must be at SQL side. To read and validate 10 million rows using c# will take a long time. Between option 1 and 2 is your call, but you still have to read all records and validate them.